# sqlalchemy query from sorted columns in time series

Tags: database, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have a sqlite table defined as:

```
class HourlyUserWebsite(Base):                                                                                                                                                                              
    __tablename__ = 'hourly_user_website'                                                                                                                                                                   

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)                                                                                                                                                                  
    user = Column(String(600), index=True)                                                                                                                                                                  
    domain = Column(String(600))                                                                                                                                                                            
    time_secs = Column(Integer, index=True)                                                                                                                                                                 

    def __repr__(self):                                                                                                                                                                                     
        return "HourlyUserWebsite(user='%s', domain='%s', time_secs=%d)"  % \                                                                                                                               
            (self.user, self.domain, self.time_secs)
```

and I add elements to it with a class method as:

```
   def add_elements_to_hourly_db(self, data, start_secs, end_secs, engine):                                                                                                                                
        session = self._get_session(engine)                                                                                                                                                                 
        for el in data:                                                                                                                                                                                     
            session.add(el)                                                                                                                                                                                 
        session.commit()                                                                                                                                                                                    
        return
```

as the data is time series I am expecting to add always elements with increasing or equal time_secs value (not decreasing).

I get the data from the table with a query like: 
`session.query(HorlyUserWebsite)`

I'd like to have the  results from the query sorted by `time_secs` and by `user`.

Is there any way I can do it?  Can the data be stored in such a way that query for sorted data is optimised keeping in mind that it is a time series?

Answer (score 0):

```
session.query(HourlyUserWebsite).order_by(HourlyUserWebsite.user,HourlyUserWebsite.time_secs.desc()).all()
```

Comment: what is the complexity of the operation? I am afraid that this may not be taking advantage from the fact that the data is inserted in a sorted (in time) order already

Comment: I highly doubt there will be any performance difference. Particularly if your user and time_secs are already indexes. Indexed data will also get stored differently on disk than insert order in anyway. If you do run into performance issues you could move to PostgreSQL.